# index.html did not match any routes - react-router - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm confused. without `html-webpack-plugin` plugin I can run my project and it works fine:

```
yarn start
```

url:

http://localhost:3000/

My project is finished. now I want to build my project and I want to upload on server.

my project works with Api.

now, I think I should use `html-webpack-plugin` to get a build file.
to do this I run this command:

```
npm run build
```

and It makes a `dist` directory that inside of it is:

[image]

---

I uploaded my content of my dist on server:

http://www.shadyab.com/test20/index.html

I got this error on console:

`Warning: [react-router] Location "/test20/index.html" did not match any routes`

whole my project:

https://github.com/smemamian/shadyab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hit root url i.e. `/` not `index.html`

http://www.shadyab.com/test20

If you want to map `/index.html` to root url, add a rule in react-router.

[image]

Comment: but I got the same error with your url: `http://www.shadyab.com/test20`

Comment: I got some UI with bad css :)